# Removing old facebook account that is no longer used

Tags: facebook

My problem is that I have an account I last used two years ago. I opened another one. I no longer have the phone number and I have long forgotten the password & email, but I want it deleted completely because old friends are still posting, and even hackers are abusing it to post some things. Yet I no longer have access to it.

How can I delete it?

Comment: Which of the two accounts are you trying to delete?

Answer (score 1):

A simple Google search provided [this answer](https://www.facebook.com/help/132243923516844).

**I can’t reset my password because I can't access the email address listed on my account.**

You may be able to get back into your Facebook account by answering a security question, using an alternate email address listed on your account or [getting help from friends](https://www.facebook.com/help/215543298568604). Keep in mind that you'll only see these options if you set them up.

To see if you have these options:

1. Go to the Facebook login page and click [Forgot your password? or Can't login?](https://www.facebook.com/login/identify) in the top right.
2. Fill out the form to identify your account.
3. Select **I forgot my password** on the next page if prompted.
4. Look at the list of email addresses listed on your account. If you don't have access to any of these, click **No longer have access to these?**
5. Follow the directions provided to answer your security question or get help from friends, if you see these options, or contact your email service provider.

Once you get back into your account you can change your login email address at any time from your [account settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings). You can also log into Facebook with any email address you've added to your account.